# how to remove the black screen ubuntu after login

Tags: 16.04

I have ubuntu 16.04, this morning like every day I open my ubuntu and when l but my password for login,the screen become black
Please help me for remove the black screen.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/363238/197910 may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Login into tty1 (ctrl+alt+F1) and make some free space and also remove .xsession from home directory if it is there.

Get back to login UI using ctrl+alt+F7 and check again.